# Trouble with .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(css|js|images)
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9-]+).html index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

This is as far as I could get, it doesn't seem to meet all the qualifications that I need. Basically, if a user on my site goes to *mydomain.com/([A-Za-z0-9-]+).html*, I want my server to see *mydomain.com/index.php?page=$1*. If they go to any other file, or a folder other than css, images, js, or js/util, I want the server to see *mydomain.com/index.php?* or *mydomain.com/index.php?page=*. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ([A-z0-9\-]+).html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

1. Use `\-` inside the set matching.
2. Instead of `!-d`, I think you need to use [`!-f`](http://amandine.aupetit.info/135/apache2-mod_rewrite/).

Take a look at [THIS](http://amandine.aupetit.info/135/apache2-mod_rewrite/) link.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This doesn't seem to solve the problem when I visit mydomain.com/portfolio

Comment: I want to handle any possible input, so I can display an error page if I need to.